# Suggestion box - Web Part submit item to a list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am usign SharePoint 2010, and I want to create a suggestion box, something simple that I can use as a webpart.

I only need a multiple line textbox and a "Submit" button, and store this information in a list.

Can this be done out of the box or do I need to develop a new webpart?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a list with mananged metadata column and add it to a list. To column will have suggestions from the term set that you define.